# SqlDataSource not Working

Tags: asp.net, sql

```
Select pmtblempreg.Id
      ,pmtblempreg.Name
      ,pmtblempreg.UserName
      ,pmtbldesignation.Designation
      , pmtblempreg.skypeid
      ,pmtblempreg.EmailId 
From pmtbldesignation
Right join pmtblempreg  ON 
      pmtbldesignation.Id = pmtblempreg.DesignationId
```

This query works fine in oracle database. But when executing using sqlDataSource for populating a gridview an error is showing that invalid table name

when i execute it through the query builder of sqldataSource the query changes to

```
 SELECT PMTBLEMPREG.ID
       ,PMTBLEMPREG.NAME
       ,PMTBLEMPREG.USERNAME
       ,PMTBLDESIGNATION.DESIGNATION
       ,PMTBLEMPREG.SKYPEID
       ,PMTBLEMPREG.EMAILID
 FROM { **oj PMTBLDESIGNATION** 
         RIGHT OUTER JOIN PMTBLEMPREG ON
               PMTBLDESIGNATION.ID = PMTBLEMPREG.DESIGNATIONID
      }
```

an oj is automatically created along with the table name.

Is that the problem??

Comment: yes try that without oj

Comment: Connection string is correct.I tested it using Test Connection button in sqldatasource.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PE.ID
       ,PE.NAME
       ,PE.USERNAME
       ,PD.DESIGNATION
       ,PE.SKYPEID
       ,PE.EMAILID
 FROM PMTBLDESIGNATION PD
         RIGHT OUTER JOIN PMTBLEMPREG PE ON
               PD.ID = PE.DESIGNATIONID
```

where **`PD`** is the Table name alias for **`PMTBLDESIGNATION`**  and **`PE`** is the Table name alias for **`PMTBLEMPREG`**

**Updated:**

By default if you execute the query it checks the table in the Master Database

Instead before executing query Write this code

**`Use Your_database_name`**

The database name is where the tables are placed.

Try this

Hope this Helps

Comment: check with the database name, where you have the tables

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Just Use this code in CodeBehid

```
Dim SQLStatement As String = "Select pmtblempreg.Id,pmtblempreg.Name,pmtblempreg.UserName     ,pmtbldesignation.Designation, pmtblempreg.skypeid,pmtblempreg.EmailId From pmtbldesignation
Right join pmtblempreg  ON pmtbldesignation.Id = pmtblempreg.DesignationId"

sqldatsrc.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
sqldatsrc.SelectCommand = SQLStatement
```

Or Paste the query in SQLDatasource Select Command as

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=xx;User ID=xx;Password=xxx" ProviderName="xx" SelectCommand="Select pmtblempreg.Id,pmtblempreg.Name,pmtblempreg.UserName     ,pmtbldesignation.Designation, pmtblempreg.skypeid,pmtblempreg.EmailId From pmtbldesignation
Right join pmtblempreg  ON pmtbldesignation.Id = pmtblempreg.DesignationId"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I tried it but not working.... I changed the query with inner join,then it is working fine... but when i add right join or left join it is not working..

Comment: @user3098174 refer this http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/join-data-sources-in-a-query-HA102749779.aspx#_Toc311116342